# Solution to congruence $z^2=c$ mod n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Could someone help me out with this? Not sure if I know all the tools to solve it.

Let n be an int that is square free and odd with gcd(n,c)=1.

Show that there is a z with $z^2=c$ mod n iff (c/p)=1 for all primes p that divide n.

Comment: chinese remainder theorem

Comment: The assertion is not quite right. It should say "Show that there is a $z$ such fhat $z^2\equiv c\pmod{n}$ iff $\dots$".

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

1) $z^2\equiv c\ (\ mod\ n)$ means $n|z^2-c$, which holds if and only if
       $p|z^2-c$ for every prime $p$ dividing $n$. The reason for this is the chinese remainder theorem, mentioned by Will Jagy.

2) Consider $(\frac{c}{p})=1$ if and only if there is a number $x$ with $x^2\equiv c\ (\ mod\ p\ )$ (Legendre-symbol)